# how to use insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ""); on replace() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
sentences.innerHTML.replace(c, "<mark>" + it + "</mark>");
```

I learn that `innerHTML` remove all event listener, it causes all my other click event cannot be triggered.

I also learn that in order to avoid removing event listener, we may use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead of `innerHTML`.

But when I use `insertAdjacentHTML` , it add new content, not replace old content. How to replace old content by `insertAdjacentHTML` ?

```
function mark(it) {
    clearIt();
    if (it.length > 0) {
        let c = new RegExp(it, "ig");
        let sentences = document.getElementById('sentences');
        sentences.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sentences.innerHTML.replace(c, "<mark>" + it + "</mark>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.   You want to *replace* the HTML, but *keep* the event handlers.    Take a sheet of paper, write an X on it, now throw that paper and away and get another piece.  Why would you expect that new piece to have an X on it?   Instead, use event delegation.

Comment: *Jquery function* - there's no [tag:jquery] in this question.   Be sure to know what [tag:jquery] is and how to use it.

Comment: *I also learn that in order to avoid removing event listener, we may use insertAdjacentHTML* - this is incorrect.   This will add *new* HTML and that new HTML will not have event handlers either.   there's no difference.   Depends on how you add your event handlers add exactly to what elements.

Comment: Agreed with @freedomn-m : ___Instead, use event delegation___

Comment: @freedomn-m (sorry I had to correct myself ;-P) re-"there's no difference". There is in the case one of the children of the parent node (so a sibling of the new content) has events attached to it (or if some JS has references to them).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @Kaiido to clarify: There's no difference *for the newly inserted HTML* with regard to event handlers assigned to existing elements within the parent.   ie the *new* HTML added with `insertAdjacentHTML` is exactly the same as *new* HTML added with `.replace`.    The existing elements will retain their events if they are not removed - so, yes, there's a difference in the final outcome - *only new with no events* vs *old with events and new with no events*.

Comment: This should answer your question (or at least what appears to be what you want answered): [event binding on dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

First bring your old content,

```
var oldContent = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
```

then, remove it,

```
if (oldContent.length != 0) oldContent.remove();
```

and then, add your new content,

```
let newContent = "<p class='text'>My new paragraph.</p>";
sentence.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", newContent);
```

Might not be a good solution, but will work.

Comment: *but will work* - what do you mean by "will work"?  Will it be the same as `.innerHTML =`?  Yes.   Is that the problem that OP has?  Yes.   So how does this solve OP's problem of losing event handlers on elements that have been removed?  Does that problem make no sense?  Yes, but that's what's been asked.